# merging two different date time column to form a sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data sets.One with weekly date time and the other hourly date time.
my data sets looks like this:-

```
df1
Week_date               w_values
21-04-2019 20:00:00      10
28-04-2019 20:00:00      20
05-05-2019 20:00:00      30

df2
hour_date                 h_values
19-04-2019 08:00:00         a
21-04-2019 07:00:00         b
21-04-2019 20:00:00         c
22-04-2019 06:00:00         d
23-04-2019 05:00:00         e
28-04-2019 19:00:00         f
28-04-2019 20:00:00         g
28-04-2019 21:00:00         h
29-04-2019 20:00:00         i
05-05-2019 20:00:00         j
06-05-2019 23:00:00         k
```

tried merging but failed to get the desired output

output data set should look like this

```
week_date               w_values        hour_date                h_values
21-04-2019 20:00:00      10             21-04-2019 20:00:00         c
21-04-2019 20:00:00      10             22-04-2019 06:00:00         d
21-04-2019 20:00:00      10             23-04-2019 05:00:00         e
21-04-2019 20:00:00      10             28-04-2019 19:00:00         f
28-04-2019 20:00:00      20             28-04-2019 20:00:00         g
28-04-2019 20:00:00      20             28-04-2019 21:00:00         h
28-04-2019 20:00:00      20             29-04-2019 20:00:00         i
05-05-2019 20:00:00      30             05-05-2019 20:00:00         j
05-05-2019 20:00:00      30             06-05-2019 23:00:00         k
```

the weekly date will change only when week date is equal to hour date....else it will take previous week date....

Comment: how do you have `06-05-2019 24:00:00 ` as date? i think 24:00:00 would be the next day `00:00:00` no?

Comment: it's 06-05-2019 23:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do (provided `Week_date` and `hour_date` are datetimes):

```
(df2.merge(df1, how='left', right_on='Week_date', left_on='hour_date')
    .ffill()
    .dropna())
```

### The way it works

Make sure both dfs are sorted

```
>>> df1 = df1.sort_values('Week_date')
>>> df2 = df2.sort_values('hour_date')
```

Do the merge

```
>>> df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', right_on='Week_date', left_on='hour_date')
>>> df3
             hour_date h_values           Week_date  w_values
0  2019-04-19 08:00:00        a                 NaT       NaN
1  2019-04-21 07:00:00        b                 NaT       NaN
2  2019-04-21 20:00:00        c 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
3  2019-04-22 06:00:00        d                 NaT       NaN
4  2019-04-23 05:00:00        e                 NaT       NaN
5  2019-04-28 19:00:00        f                 NaT       NaN
6  2019-04-28 20:00:00        g 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
7  2019-04-28 21:00:00        h                 NaT       NaN
8  2019-04-29 20:00:00        i                 NaT       NaN
9  2019-05-05 20:00:00        j 2019-05-05 20:00:00      30.0
10 2019-06-05 23:00:00        k                 NaT       NaN
```

Forward fill the gaps

```
>>> df3 = df3.ffill()
>>> df3
             hour_date h_values           Week_date  w_values
0  2019-04-19 08:00:00        a                 NaT       NaN
1  2019-04-21 07:00:00        b                 NaT       NaN
2  2019-04-21 20:00:00        c 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
3  2019-04-22 06:00:00        d 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
4  2019-04-23 05:00:00        e 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
5  2019-04-28 19:00:00        f 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
6  2019-04-28 20:00:00        g 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
7  2019-04-28 21:00:00        h 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
8  2019-04-29 20:00:00        i 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
9  2019-05-05 20:00:00        j 2019-05-05 20:00:00      30.0
10 2019-06-05 23:00:00        k 2019-05-05 20:00:00      30.0
```

Remove the remaining `NaN`s

```
>>> df3 = df3.dropna()
>>> df3
             hour_date h_values           Week_date  w_values
2  2019-04-21 20:00:00        c 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
3  2019-04-22 06:00:00        d 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
4  2019-04-23 05:00:00        e 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
5  2019-04-28 19:00:00        f 2019-04-21 20:00:00      10.0
6  2019-04-28 20:00:00        g 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
7  2019-04-28 21:00:00        h 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
8  2019-04-29 20:00:00        i 2019-04-28 20:00:00      20.0
9  2019-05-05 20:00:00        j 2019-05-05 20:00:00      30.0
10 2019-06-05 23:00:00        k 2019-05-05 20:00:00      30.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'merge_asof' function. From pandas documentation "This merge is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys."

```
df_week['Week_date']=pd.to_datetime(df_week['Week_date'])
df_hour['hour_date']=pd.to_datetime(df_hour['hour_date'])

df_week_sort=df_week.sort_values(by='Week_date')
df_hour_sort=df_hour.sort_values(by='hour_date')

df_week_sort.rename(columns={'Week_date':'Merge_date'},inplace=True)
df_hour_sort.rename(columns={'hour_date':'Merge_date'},inplace=True)

df_merged=pd.merge_asof(df_hour_sort,df_week_sort,on='Merge_date')
```

Make sure that the two frames are sorted by the date stamp